# Saving multiple URLs at once using Linux Centos

Tags: linux, url, centos, save

So i have a list of about 1000 urls in a txt file, one per line, I wish to save the contents of every page to a file, how can i automate this?"

Comment: Do you know about `curl` or `wget`? They do this. And then, to loop through lines of files you can check many answers in this site. Give a try, show your attempt and indicate if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Im fairly ne to linux, could you explain this more, possibly tell me the code needed? would really appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wget` with the `-i` option to let it download a list of URLs. Assuming your URLs are stored in a file called `urls.txt`:

```
wget -i urls.txt
```

The problem here might be that the filenames can be the same for multiple websites (e.g. `index.html`), so that `wget` will append a number which makes it hard/impossible to connect a file to the original URL just by looking at the filename.
The solution to that would be to use a loop like this:

```
while read -r line
do
  wget "$line" -O <...>
done < urls.txt
```

You can specify a custom filename with the `-O` option.

Or you can "build" the file name from the url you are processing.

```
while read -r line
do
  fname=$(echo  "$line" | sed -e 's~http[s]*://~~g' -e 's~[^A-Za-z0-9]~-~g')
  fname=${fname}.html
  wget "$line" -O "$fname"
done < urls.txt
```